# make sure when my WPF application window opens that is visible on one of my monitors

Tags: wpf

If my WPF application window opens and it is not on one of my monitors, I would like to reposition to my primary monitor. This happens often when my app was open on a 2nd monitor and then disconnecting that 2nd monitor and opening the app.